# jQuery script returns new window on Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, firefox, object

i have this toggle button for an element on my page, and when i click it, i can see the script runs and toggles the element, but then i get a new window with the JS object returned [i guess..]. it just a blank window with a url of my href and it says `[object Object]`
in chrome its fine, but ie and firefox do this.
they way i do this is

```
<a href="javascript:jQuery('#thatDude').toggle();">click</a>
<div id="thatDude">blah</div>
```

the even stranger part is that i also have this is my script file

```
jQuery('.someBtn').live('click', function() {
  jQuery('#someForm').toggle();
});
```

and when i click that - it works fine anywhere... [yeah i know i should change live to delegate =] ]

does anyone know whats going on?
im using jquery 1.6 [but 1.4.4 does the same..]

thanks so much

Comment: Please review your question next time before submitting it. The formatting of your question contained errors that had to be fixed. If you get this right the first time, you are more likely to receive better answers.

Comment: oh sorry about that, i didnt know its a must to wrap all code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's going on is that the return value of the script in a `javascript:` URI, if that return value is not void, is treated as HTML and parsed as such.  Except in WebKit, which doesn't implement that feature (with one exception mentioned below).  In your case, I assume that jQuery's `toggle()` returns an actual value that's not undefined, and that value is treated as a string to be parsed as HTML.

You can see the behavior in this simple testcase in IE and Firefox and Opera:

```
<a href="javascript:'<h1>some text</h1>'">Click me</a>
```

This totally fails in WebKit browsers, though this does work in WebKit because they special-hack one codepath:

```
<iframe src="javascript:'<h1>some text</h1>'"></iframe>
```

If you want to make sure your script's return value is void, put `void(0)` at the end of the script.

Comment: Awesome this worked for me on an svg <a> element.  xlink:href="javascript:$('#someid').modal('show'); void(0)"

Answer (score 0):

return false from your click event handler, that should help.