# inline javascript firefox error?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, inline

Does anyone know why when I run this code in my script it takes me to a page that just says *none* ? And it only seems to be happening in Firefox.

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';">CLOSE</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="
    javascript:document.getElementById('light')
    .style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade')
    .style.display='none';return false;">CLOSE</a>
```

However inline JS is kind of an antipattern these days, I would suggest moving this logic into a JS file and giving this link a class or something that allows you to hook into it and add an event listener for click

Comment: The only reason this works is that the `return false` throws an exception, thus terminating the script and preventing it from having a return value.  So it "works", but it's not exactly the best solution....

Comment: it doesn't "throw an exception" it just stops processing of the click event on the anchor, yes there are a few things wrong with this approach but it's the path of least resistance to get the OP's solution working.

Answer (score 1):

Assignments in JavaScript return the value that was assigned.  Firefox is evalutating all your JavaScript, and seeing that the last thing that happened was a statement that returned 'none'; it then makes that the window's location, because that's what the href attribute of a link is supposed to do.  (kind of, anyway.)

You may wish to use the onclick attribute of the anchor tag instead of the href, and add a 'return false' to the end so that the default action for clicking on links -- navigating to the href -- doesn't happen.

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
            return false;">CLOSE</a>
```

Of course, even better would be to define a function for this.  =)

Answer (score 1):

See [jQuery script returns new window on Firefox and Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933728/jquery-script-returns-new-window-on-firefox-and-internet-explorer/5939378) and my answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';" >CLOSE</a>
```

And works pretty okay on most of the web browsers.